# 'Proper' way to do row-wise replacement

Tags: r

I have a data frame which looks something like:

```
dataDemo <- data.frame(POS = 1:4 , REF = c("A" , "T" , "G" , "C") , 
    ind1 = c("A" , "." , "G" , "C") , ind2 = c("A" , "C" , "C" , "."),
                                                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

dataDemo

  POS REF ind1 ind2
1   1   A    A    A
2   2   T    .    C
3   3   G    G    C
4   4   C    C    .
```

and I'd like to replace all the "."s with the `REF` value for that row. Here is how I did it:

```
for(i in seq_along(dataDemo$REF)){
    dataDemo[i , ][dataDemo[i , ] == '.'] <- dataDemo$REF[i]
}
```

I'd like to know if there's a more 'proper' or idiomatic way of doing this in R. I generally try to use *apply whenever possible and this seems like something that could easily be adapted to that approach and made more readable (and run faster), but despite throwing a good bit of time at it I haven't made much progress.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's another `base` R alternative, where we use the row numbers of the `"."` occurrences to replace them by the appropriate `REF` values.

```
# Get row numbers
rownrs <- which(dataDemo==".", arr.ind = TRUE)[,1]

# Replace values
dataDemo[dataDemo=="."] <- dataDemo$REF[rownrs]

# Result
dataDemo
#  POS REF ind1 ind2
#1   1   A    A    A
#2   2   T    T    C
#3   3   G    G    C
#4   4   C    C    C
```

Comment: Perfectly simple. This is what happens when I go and try to learn C.

Answer (score 9):

In `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)

dataDemo %>% mutate_each(funs(ifelse(. == '.', REF, as.character(.))), -POS)
#   POS REF ind1 ind2
# 1   1   A    A    A
# 2   2   T    T    C
# 3   3   G    G    C
# 4   4   C    C    C
```

Comment: I need to invest some time in making better use of plyr and dplyr.

Comment: `plyr` is somewhat superseded by `dplyr`, so you probably only need to learn the latter. It probably won't take too long, either; it's pretty simple.

Comment: @akrun Pretty much, but it was originally posted before you added `dplyr` in the edit. Also yours will have issues if `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`.

Comment: Good catch on that. My original data set is not formatted in the way I specified with my sample dataset.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an option using `set` from `data.table`, which should be fast.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dataDemo)
nm1 <- paste0("ind", 1:2)
for(j in nm1){
    i1  <- dataDemo[[j]]=="."
    set(dataDemo, i = which(i1), j=j,  value = dataDemo$REF[i1])
 }

dataDemo
#   POS REF ind1 ind2
#1:   1   A    A    A
#2:   2   T    T    C
#3:   3   G    G    C
#4:   4   C    C    C
```

EDIT: Based on @alexis_laz's comments

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dataDemo %>% 
    mutate_each(funs(ifelse(.==".", REF,.)), ind1:ind2)
#    POS REF ind1 ind2
#1   1   A    A    A
#2   2   T    T    C
#3   3   G    G    C
#4   4   C    C    C
```

---

Or we can use `base R` methods to do this in a single line.

```
dataDemo[nm1] <- lapply(dataDemo[nm1], function(x) ifelse(x==".",  dataDemo$REF, x))
```

Comment: Saving, in each iteration, an `i = dataDemo[[j]] == "."`, to avoid computing it twice, should make it even more efficient.